# Warhmmer 40k Tyranid Tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Would it be possible to get a tag for the Tyranids army from Warhammer 40k? I noticed Tyranids is missing although it looks like some of the armies are there.

Comment: For reference we currently have tags for Tau, Necrons, and Orks (and Space Orks)

Comment: I am not familiar with the game, what does having an army tag do for the question?

Comment: @JoeW Each army has it's own rule book and this would allow me to filter for armies that I am familiar with to answer questions.

Comment: If there is a question where the tag is needed (as a tag has to be on a question to be created) and it isn't created when I get off work I can add the tag for you.

Comment: @joew yeah I just need the tags added for warhammer 40k armies. I can update the question with all the missing ones if you would like me to.

Comment: But is there an actual question where the tag can be used, and currently doesn't use?

Comment: @nij Yeah I just made one where I was specifically asking about representing a Tyranid model that doesnt have a official model but official rules for it exists.

Comment: Please provide a link to a question where this tag would be appropriate so that the tag can be added to the question. There is no way to create a tag without adding it to an existing question.

Comment: @JoeW http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34260/do-warhammer-models-that-have-no-models-have-specific-dimensions-stated-any-wher/34262#34262

Comment: So you're saying that each army is a variant of the game? Otherwise it seems like overly partitioning of the questions.

Comment: @JonTheMon Their is a core rule book and then each army has its own rule book. Then each armies rule books may have supplement books. I certainly don't think we need tags for the supplement books but a book for each of the main armies as detailed in the core rule book. This link contains all the rule books and supplements for them. In the side navigation bar you can see a list of the armies which is not one to one with books. https://www.games-workshop.com/en-US/Warhammer-40-000?Nu=product.repositoryId&N=102352+1990622255&qty=12&sorting=rec&view=table&categoryId=cat440130a-flat.

Comment: @JonTheMon The armies is what I would like to have a tag for but even some of those could be condensed into one. For instance Tyranid Cult despite being a stand alone army should probably be condensed with Tyranids since they are a supplement of Tyranids.

Comment: I think the Warhammer 40k armies could be compared to board game expansion packs, which we do frequently create tags for. They are different enough, as shown by their different rule books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created the tag [tyranids](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tyranids) for you on the question you linked. Please update the tag wiki with the appropriate information so that it does not get removed from the system.